# Pandas concat appears to ignore indices

Tags: python, pandas

I'm relatively new to Pandas. I ran into an unexpected issue with `pd.concat()` I didn't expect.

```py
df1 = pd.DataFrame([], columns=['a', 'b', 'c']).set_index(['b', 'a'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2, 3]], columns=['a', 'b', 'c']).set_index(['a', 'b']) # intentionally reverse
pd.concat([df1, df2])
```

I would expect the result of the above to be:

```
     c
a b
1 2  3
```

but instead it is:

```
     c
b a <---- note that b=1 and a=2 here
1 2  3
```

In other words, it appears that `pd.concat()` is ignoring the index headers when doing the `pd.concat()`, but then relabeling the headers after the `pd.concat()` is completed.

On the other hand, `pd.concat()` works as I would expect with column headers. The result of `pd.concat([df1.reset_index(), df2.reset_index()])` is:

```
     a    b  c
0  1.0  2.0  3
```

as expected.

Is the behavior that I observed with `pd.concat()` and indices expected behavior?

I tried Googling around, but I haven't been able to find an example of someone running into an issue similar to this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It seems that *Pandas* during *concat*:

- Takes index column names from the **first** DataFrame only.
- But for further DataFrames, only the column **numbers** matter,
  as long as index columns are matched.

So in case of *df1* MultiIndex is composed of column *1* and *0* (numeration
starts from *0*, but in *df2* and *df3* - composed of columns *0* and *1*,
**regardless of their names**.

To confirm it, try a bit wider example:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame([], columns=['a', 'b', 'c']).set_index(['b', 'a'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2, 3]], columns=['aa', 'bb', 'c']).set_index(['aa', 'bb'])
df3 = pd.DataFrame([[10, 20, 30]], columns=['xx', 'yy', 'c']).set_index(['xx', 'yy'])
pd.concat([df1, df2, df3])
```

The result is:

```
        c
b  a     
1  2    3
10 20  30
```

So as you can see, even if source column names (for index columns only)
are different, this means nothing. Only their **position** among columns is
important.

But if you change the third column name (of a **regular** column):

```
df3 = pd.DataFrame([[10, 20, 30]], columns=['xx', 'yy', 'cc']).set_index(['xx', 'yy'])
```

(*c* changed to *cc), the result is different:

```
         c    cc
b  a            
1  2   3.0   NaN
10 20  NaN  30.0
```

Comment: that's what I noticed as well. It matches up columns but not indices. Oddly, if the index is a single column, it removes the index name in the process (which is at least less confusing?).